# vulnerability scan issue: nginx HTTP Server memory disclosure via HTTP backend responses

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

nginx HTTP Server memory disclosure via HTTP backend responses.

How to fix this vulnerability scan issue in my production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory disclosure vulnerability is present in nginx versions 1.1.4 to
1.2.8 and 1.3.0 to 1.4.0. The vulnerability is present if proxy_pass to untrusted upstream HTTP servers is used. The vulnerability could also
lead to a denial of service.

This finding is based on version information which may not have been
updated by previously installed patches (e.g., Red Hat "back ports").
Please submit a "Patched Service" dispute in TrustKeeper if this
vulnerability has already been patched.

CVE: CVE-2013-2070
NVD: CVE-2013-2070
CVSSv2: AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:P
Service: nginx:nginx

Reference:
http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-announce/2013/000114.html
http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html

Upgrade the nginx to latest version that will solve all the nginx related issues.

To upgrade nginx in ubuntu: http://leftshift.io/upgrading-nginx-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-servers